# Missing iscsi_tcp kernel module in Ubuntu 21.10 for Raspberry Pi ARM64

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi, 21.10, arm64, iscsi

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 for Raspberry Pi ARM64 in order to try out the new release.

After performing an apt upgrade and updating the iscsi initiator name I tried to run

```
sudo iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal 10.1.0.20
```

but I got the following error

```
iscsiadm: read error (-1/104), daemon died?
iscsiadm: Could not scan /sys/class/iscsi_transport.
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module: could not 
find module by name='iscsi_tcp'
iscsiadm: Could not insert module tcp. Kmod error -2
iscsiadm: iSCSI driver tcp is not loaded. Load the module then retry the command.
iscsiadm: Could not perform SendTargets discovery: iSCSI driver not found. Please make sure it is loaded, and retry the operation
```

modprobe iscsi_tcp shows

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module iscsi_tcp not found in directory /lib/modules/5.13.0-1008-raspi
```

How can I enable / install / compile this missing kernel module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is included in `linux-modules-extra-*-raspi` packages.

Similar issue may solved by checking [Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=iscsi_tcp) online or [`apt-file`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) offline (but it needs to download big index files) and search the missing file.

Answer (score 1):

## EVERY KERNEL UPGRADE BREAKS iSCSI:

It's extremely important to note that the Accepted answer is **NOT** a fix-n-forget solution:

The package reference in the Accepted answer does fix the problem, but by installing a static Kernel Module. So once the Kernel is updated, the static Kernel Module is lost and you'll be back where you started: with broken iSCSI.

**So after every Kernel upgrade you must remember to execute:**

```
apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

(tested with 'ubuntu-22.04-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz')

If you forget, you will be scratching your head wondering when your iSCSI is hosed ;-)

## Finally:

Don't forget to do the housekeeping:

Find obsolete package:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra*
```

Remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-modules-extra-Prev-Pkg-Version-raspi
```

HTH-